# in dart, is there any way to limit the key in some special strings

Tags: dictionary, dart, key

i search many place, did not find any solution.
so the question is.
i want a map in dart like this

```
var Map<String, String> data;
```

it will be a params init and passed in other place. but when pass the params， i want to limit the key in map only accept some special strings. like 'someA', 'someB'.
so，when call the function it like this.

```
functionA({'someA': 'xxxx', 'someB': 'xxxx'})
```

no other keys.

and also when i call the function i can just type some word and the IDE will show suggestion for me to select the key.

the all code like this (can not run).

```
var List<String> keyList = ['someA', 'someB'];
class Abc {
    functionA({Map<valueOf keyList, String> data) {

    }
}

Abc().functionA({'someA': 'xxxx', 'someB': 'xxxx'});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can provide your own `Map` implementation (deriving from [`DelegatingMap`](https://pub.dev/documentation/collection/latest/collection/DelegatingMap-class.html) from [`package:collection`](https://pub.dev/packages/collection) would make it a lot easier) and then override `operator []=` to throw if the supplied key should not be allowed.  For example:

```dart
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

/// A [Map] that allows only certain keys.
class LimitedMap<K, V> extends DelegatingMap<K, V> {
  LimitedMap({Iterable<K> allowedKeys})
      : allowedKeys = <K>{...allowedKeys},
        super(<K, V>{});

  final Set<K> allowedKeys;

  /// Throws an exception if [key] is not allowed.
  void _checkKey(K key) {
    if (!allowedKeys.contains(key)) {
      throw Exception('Invalid key: $key');
    }
  }

  @override
  void addAll(Map<K, V> other) => addEntries(other.entries);

  @override
  void addEntries(Iterable<MapEntry<K, V>> entries) {
    for (var entry in entries) {
      this[entry.key] = entry.value;
    }
  }

  @override
  V putIfAbsent(K key, V Function() ifAbsent) {
    _checkKey(key);
    return super.putIfAbsent(key, ifAbsent);
  }

  @override
  V update(K key, V Function(V) update, {V Function() ifAbsent}) {
    _checkKey(key);
    return super.update(key, update, ifAbsent: ifAbsent);
  }

  @override
  void operator []=(K key, V value) {
    _checkKey(key);
    super[key] = value;
  }
}

class MyMap extends LimitedMap<String, String> {
  MyMap([Map<String, String> initialMap])
      : super(allowedKeys: {'foo', 'bar', 'baz'}) {
    if (initialMap != null) {
      addAll(initialMap);
    }
  }
}
```

Alternatively, if your keys are fixed, it'd be better to just make them properties on a custom class, and then you also would get the IDE autocompletion behavior that you want.

Comment: Thank you very much.
but i searched for many times, and did not find any example for the DelegatingMap, so would you give an example for the DelegatingMap.
and some comment for the question was added.
it is: and also when i call the function i can just type some word and the IDE will show suggestion for me to select the key.

Comment: @yimity I've updated my answer with an example.